# changing password - issue with ldap update

Tags: ldap, centos7, sssd, pam-ldap, 389-ds

I have set directory 389 and 1 server to be client for testing authentication of users, etc.

For installation of Directory I have used this tutorial:

[Install And Configure LDAP Server In CentOS 7](https://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-ldap-server-in-centos-7/)

For installing client I have used this tutorial:
[How to Install Configure LDAP Client for 389 Directory Server](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/10/389-ldap-client/)

Now ds-389 and client authentication works, but when I try to change password of ldap user I get some weird message:

> May 20 13:40:55 server passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "test"
>   does not exist in /etc/passwd May 20 13:41:06 server passwd:
>   pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "test" does not exist in /etc/passwd
>   May 20 13:41:06 server passwd: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): password
>   change failed: password change failed: Confidentiality required;
>   user=test May 20 13:41:06 server passwd: gkr-pam: couldn't change
>   password for the login keyring: the passwords didn't match. May 20
>   13:41:06 server passwd: gkr-pam: stopped the daemon

Does anyone know what can be the problem?
my pam config looks like this:

password-auth:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok


password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in my case I wasted one full day of playing with configuration and wireshark to find out that in order to have ability for users to change their password, you need to have on ds-389 encryption enabled, and your client needs to connect to port 636 SSL/TLS to "SECURELY" pass confidential data, in our case password.
Kinda feel stupid after skipping most important part ;D

So in order for system to run properly, first we need to generate certificate on ds-389

For this, I used this short tutorial:
[Configure TLS SSL 389 Directory Server CentOS](https://mewattech.blogspot.com/2015/06/configure-tls-ssl-389-directory-server.html)

Please be aware to set PIN for your ds-389 and restart services, of course...
So after you have set everything on your ds-389, next step is to put client to connect to specific port.
As prerequisite, you need to export crt to pem by using this command:

```
openssl x509 -in ca-cert.crt -out ca-cert.pem -outform PEM
```

copy that ca-cert.pem to your (client) for example from home folder where you scp ca-cert.pem (or wherever you copied that file)

```
mv (scp-cert-path)/ca-cert.pem /etc/openldap/cacerts/
```

And as a final step use authconfig-tui to set your client to use TLS instead of 389 port with plain text...

You can follow these steps from this link:
[How to Install Configure LDAP Client for 389 Directory Server](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/10/389-ldap-client/)

I hope that I helped someone to save some time and torture of Google-ing around ;)
Cheers.